# RegEx for matching everything with specific words

Tags: regex

I would like to conduct regex substitution. Here is the pattern I am using:

```
.*?fee.*?$|.*?charge.*?$
```

The matches the desired lines

- "**fee**s credit card"
- "**charge**s for interest"

However, it is also matching on coffee and feeder (I want to be specific that it does not match "coffee" or "feed" lines, how can I specifically prevent these matches but still handle cases like fee, fees)

- "cof**fee** shop"
- **feed**er cattle

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with 2 [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` to prevent the words being part of a larger word.

For you example data, if you want to match the single or single or plural version you can make the `s` at the end optional by using a question mark.

```
^.*\b(?:fees?|charges?)\b.*$
```

- `^` Start of the string
- `.*\b` Match any char except a newline followed by a word boundary
- `(?:fees?|charges?)` Match any of the listed followed by an optional `s`
- `\b.*` Word boundary, match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `$` Assert end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MBgYM2/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to match those two lines, you can simply use an expression similar to this:

```
^(fees|charges).+$
```

[image]

If you wish to match certain words, you might add boundaries to group one similar to [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/6z62bO/1):

```
^\b(fees|fee|charge|charges)\b(.+)$
```

[image]

If your pattern might be in the middle of string inputs, you can add another group in the left, similar to [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/SfdH1Z/1):

```
(?:.+|)\b(fees|fee|charge|charges)\b(?:.+|)$
```

[image]

This graph shows how an expression like that would work:

[image]

Regular expression design can be achieved much easier, if/when there is real data.